# ElasticSearch Crashing repeatedly

Tags: elasticsearch

I run ElasticSearch 1.6.2 on debian GNU/Linux 8 server

Elastic search fall repeatedly, apparently for no reason

I don't have any error messages in ElasticSearch logs but I have some warnings :

before a crash :

```
[2016-02-11 05:10:21,893][INFO ][monitor.jvm              ] [noeud-0] [gc][young][5554661][67] duration [790ms], collections [1]/[1s], total [790ms]/[1.9m], memory [320mb]->[320mb]/[1.9gb], all_pools {[young] [266.2mb]->[266.2mb]/[266.2mb]}{[survivor] [1.2mb]->[1.2mb]/[33.2mb]}{[old] [52.5mb]->[52.5mb]/[1.6gb]}
[2016-02-11 20:42:08,422][INFO ][monitor.jvm              ] [noeud-0] [gc][young][5610361][68] duration [808ms], collections [1]/[1.6s], total [808ms]/[1.9m], memory [319.8mb]->[56.7mb]/[1.9gb], all_pools {[young] [265.8mb]->[3.3mb]/[266.2mb]}{[survivor] [801.6kb]->[361.7kb]/[33.2mb]}{[old] [53.2mb]->[53.2mb]/[1.6gb]}
```

and after the crash and the restart :

```
[2016-02-12 12:08:22,472][INFO ][node                     ] [noeud-0] version[1.6.2], pid[833], build[6220391/2015-07-29T09:24:47Z]
[2016-02-12 12:08:22,473][INFO ][node                     ] [noeud-0] initializing ...
[2016-02-12 12:08:22,609][INFO ][plugins                  ] [noeud-0] loaded [], sites [head]
[2016-02-12 12:08:22,661][INFO ][env                      ] [noeud-0] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/simfs)]], net usable_space [17.2gb], net total_space [20gb], types [simfs]
[2016-02-12 12:08:25,480][INFO ][node                     ] [noeud-0] initialized
[2016-02-12 12:08:25,481][INFO ][node                     ] [noeud-0] starting ...
[2016-02-12 12:08:25,570][INFO ][transport                ] [noeud-0] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/ip.ip.ip.ip:9300]}
[2016-02-12 12:08:25,649][INFO ][discovery                ] [noeud-0] my_cluster_name/123abc
[2016-02-12 12:08:29,436][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [noeud-0] new_master [noeud-0][123abc][java8][inet[/ip.ip.ip.ip:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2016-02-12 12:08:29,462][INFO ][http                     ] [noeud-0] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/ip.ip.ip.ip:9200]}
[2016-02-12 12:08:29,463][INFO ][node                     ] [noeud-0] started
[2016-02-12 12:08:29,496][INFO ][gateway                  ] [noeud-0] recovered [1] indices into cluster_state
[2016-02-12 19:12:05,812][WARN ][monitor.jvm              ] [noeud-0] [gc][young][25368][2] duration [1.5s], collections [1]/[2.7s], total [1.5s]/[1.5s], memory [295.2mb]->[29.3mb]/[1.9gb], all_pools {[young] [266.2mb]->[4.9mb]/[266.2mb]}{[survivor] [28.9mb]->[15mb]/[33.2mb]}{[old] [0b]->[9.4mb]/[1.6gb]}
```

I read that ElasticSearch could be kill by the OOM-Killer but there is no `\var\log\kern.log` file to check that

What can I do to investigate and find the reason why ElasticSearch crash?

Comment: Your nodes are likely running out of memory. You don't see any OutOfMemoryErrors in the logs?

Comment: The only logs I have are [INFO] or [WARN] [monitor.jvm] in all elasticsearch logs files

Comment: Then there must be something killing ES.